# Open tab, wait for it to finish loading then close it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I have written my first chrome extension today. What I want it to do is open a tab in the background (pinned), and after the page in the tab finishes loading, I want the tab to close.

So far I have:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: target, selected: false, pinned: true});
```

What the above code does is open the tab in the background, and pin it.

How do I close the tab once it has finished loading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either bind a [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) or a [`chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onCompleted) event to detect that a page has finished loading, or insert a content script to close the tab.

### Using the `webNavigation.onCompleted` event

```
var tabsToClose = {};
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
    if (details.frameId !== 0) return; // Only process top-frame requests
    var tabId = details.tabId;
    if (tabsToClose[tabId]) {
        delete tabsToClose[tabId];
        chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);
    }
});

chrome.tabs.create({url: target, selected: false, pinned: true}, function(tab) {
    tabsToClose[tab.id] = 1;
});
```

Note: I assumed that navigation will always succeed. You should also bind a [`webNavigation.onErrorOccurred`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onErrorOccurred) event to close the tab on failure.

### Using a content script

By using `runAt: 'document_idle'` (default), `window.close();` will be inserted once the page has finished loading.

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: target, selected: false, pinned: true}, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        code: 'window.close();',
        runAt: 'document_idle'
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried both solutions, but neither worked.
The first one didn't open the tab at all, and the second opened the tab but didn't close it (the code wasn't executing, I replaced the `window.close()` with `alert()` and removed runAt and it still didn't work). Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: @ramo Did you request the `tabs` permission and the origin permission for the given url? See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. Is there anyway to hide the tab? like only show an alert message when that page has been loaded

Comment: @ramo You mean to open a tab which is not visible at all? There was an experimental `chrome.experimental.offscreenTabs` API, but it has been dropped because of the lack of maintenance. You could use `chrome.windows.query` to find a non-focused window, and open a tab in it (via `windowId`).

Comment: @ramo Depends on what you want. If you want to make a request, then yes, AJAX is a great solution. After adding the permission for the host to the manifest file, you'll be able to create a cross-origin request in your Chrome extension.

Comment: Sorry for all these questions. But can I use ajax to go to the URL and when its loaded alert the user?

Comment: @ramo Yes, use the `onload` event of the `XMLHttpRequest` to see when the request has finished.

Comment: Do I have to add all URLs to the permissions?

Comment: @ramo Just the URL you want to access. It's good practice to not request too much permissions without purpose. E.g. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/*` if you want to only scrape questions from Stack Overflow (opposed to `http://stackoverflow.com/*` or even `*://*/*` or `<all_urls>`)

Answer (score 7):

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: target, selected: false, pinned: true}, myTab => {
    function listener(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        // make sure the status is 'complete' and it's the right tab
        if (tabId === myTab.id && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
            chrome.tabs.remove(myTab.id);
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener);
        }
    };
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(listener);
});
```

Comment: This is a much more recent answer than the accepted one (which is outdated) and worked right away.