# Chrome Extension Scraping Loop

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to learn web scraping through chrome extensions. I scrape some hard to scrape things and I have built some custom scraping extensions. This is the first one where I am trying to loop, and automatically open and hopefully close tabs in a loop.

The problem I have seems to have to do with active = false windows. When I use active = true windows I get presumably all the AJAX  loading of the page however I don't get the full data when I do it with false windows. It is like the AJAX loading doesn't occur.

I believe my code fires when the page is fully loaded.

I scrape these pages normally by simply loading the page active and sending a message from the content to a textarea using the same code as in payload.js. Then I finish parsing in PHP ;(

I used this answer in my solution. [Open tab, wait for it to finish loading then close it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130850/open-tab-wait-for-it-to-finish-loading-then-close-it)

Does anyone know why I get different results using the same content script (payload.js) for active and inactive windows?

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Loop",
    "description": "A simple Looping page-scraping extension.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "author": "willrich33",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["popup.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/",
        "storage"
    ],
    
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "all_frames": true,
        "js": ["jquery-3.6.0.min.js"],
        "run_at":"document_start"
    }],
    
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "logo.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

popup.js

```
//Simple button on the popup
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    
    var btn = document.getElementById('myOpen');
    
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {       
                       
        var arr = document.getElementById('pagearea').value.split("\n");
        var urls = arr.map(element => {
           return element.trim();
        });
        
        document.getElementById('pagearea').value = "";
             
        create_tab(urls);       

    });
});

//Javascript Promise timer
const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

// We need to wrap the loop into an async function for this to work
async function create_tab (urls) { 

//loop through urls
for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    
    chrome.tabs.create({url: urls[i], selected: false }, myTab => {
      
      function listener(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
          // make sure the status is 'complete' and it's the right tab
          if (tabId === myTab.id && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
              
              chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().chrome.tabs.executeScript(
                      tabId, 
                      { file: 'payload.js' },
             );
              
             chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener);
          }
      }
      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(listener);
    });
    
    await timer(10000); // then the created Promise can be awaited
  }
}

// Listen to messages from the payload.js script and write to popout.html
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    
    document.getElementById('pagearea').value =  message;
    
});
```

payload.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.body.outerHTML);
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Loop</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Loop</h1>
    <p id='pagetitle'></p>
    <textarea id='pagearea' cols="40" rows="6"></textarea><br>
    <button id="myOpen">Open Page</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```